# How do I add a new file type to the 'Import' menu?

Tags: python, mesh, import

I want to add a new file type to Blender's "Import" menu. I've looked at the STL and PLY implementations but am still having troubles. Is there any documentation or examples describing the minimal API needed to add a file importer?

Comment: Yep, *Text Editor > Templates > Python > Operator File Import*.

Answer (score 2):

There is a actually a template for exactly this purpose that comes with Blender. *Text Editor > Templates > Python > Operator File Import*.